# How to set Google Analytics js expiry time

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-analytics, browser-cache

I am using Google Analytics in my one of website. Using the code given below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

          ga('create', 'UA-54841885-1', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Now whenever i test my website on various page speed tools to determine my website speed, it always gives an error of **Leverage Browser Caching** for **analytics.js** file. I already set the expiration time for the JS file but why these files are not consider for it.

Website Framework : GWT

So i just want to know that the above code is right for using google analytics for it can be modified so **Leverage Browser Caching** problem is solved for analytics.js otherwise i do something in my web application for it

Answer (score 0):

Code you wrote is correct. Analytics.js library is cached and its usual response is **304 Not Modified**.

If you want to cache it locally, be sure you provide regular updates of analytics.js copy.

This process is not recommended due to common library updates.